# The lacking parts/functions/components of React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

By far, what do you think about the parts/functions or components that React Native is lack to be officially released ?
And how did you overcome the issues related to those things ?

Answer (score 1):

You have the power of `IOS` and `Andriod` to create your own components. If you have never done it before it can seem a little daunting, but once you get your first basic component out you would see that creating custom components and functionality and importing it to the `js` side is quite easy. I'm not a fan of `Objective C` I have never tried swift though it was pretty new when I was working on RN projects, but it gets the job done. One thing you have to be careful about is the lack of `callbacks`. Data needs to be sent from the bottom up. It's not a big deal though you can make some services to get the data if you need to. It's just an extra layer. Those are the big drawbacks I can think of.

Edit: 
@BùiQuangTuấn  They already do that and it only applies purely to the react native framework. That's because react-native works the same way as react. One direction data flow. But when you mix react native and native components you're working outside of the framework. Take a look at this link [Bridging in react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/communication-ios.html) and a more indepth answer [Here](https://tadeuzagallo.com/blog/react-native-bridge/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. But I think when Facebook decided to develop a framework like RN, they should give everything that pure JS devs need to build native apps. The bridging solution for sharing native code is just temporally (my opinion).